# Extract part of the string based - R

Tags: r

HI have below df and I need to extract part of it based on number of characters.

From column text1 I just need a number 16593 for id 1 and 10227 for id 2.

Desired results are:

```
    id text1
    1  16593 
    2  10227
```

Desired number is always in that string `"no_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>16593"` so I have tried to extract number based on 45 characters from word no_i and the end is

Anyone know how can I do it?

My df is below please.

```
 id <- c(1,2)
text1 <- c( 
  "<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 standalone=yes?><businessObjectChanges version=1><table><datetime>1556122543608</datetime><name>header</name><row><datetime>1556122543608</datetime><transactionType>UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>status</name><newValue>14</newValue><oldValue>13</oldValue><mimeType>INT</mimeType></column><column><name>no_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>16593</newValue><oldValue>16593</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>",
  "<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 standalone=yes?><businessObjectChanges version=1><table><datetime>1547028713373</datetime><name>header</name><row><datetime>1547028713373</datetime><transactionType>UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>status</name><newValue>14</newValue><oldValue>13</oldValue><mimeType>INT</mimeType></column><column><name>no_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>10227</newValue><oldValue>10227</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>"

)
    my_text <- data.frame (id, text1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
my_text$text1 = gsub(".*>(.*)","\\1",my_text$text1)

> my_text
  id text1
1  1 16593
2  2  1022
```

The regex basically looks for anything (`.*`) until the last occurrence of `>` and keeps only the next (which is your number).
**Alternative**

As an alternative, you can use

```
gsub(".*<newValue>(\\d+)<\\/newValue>.*","\\1",my_text$text1)
```

If your digits are always enclosed between `<newValue>`.

Comment: it work for this one but my string is much longer hence i needed to base on number of characters from no_i. Updated query.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative, which also works with your update. Let me know if there is any case for which it won't.

Comment: Jestes boski :) unless you ain't speak Polish. you are a star!

Answer (score 0):

Following your suggestion as it is we can extract the number occurring after `"no_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>"` using `sub`.

```
my_text$num <- sub(".*no_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>(\\d+).*", 
                   "\\1", my_text$text1)

my_text[c(1, 3)]
#  id   num
#1  1 16593
#2  2 10227
```

Comment: please have a look at updated query. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kalenji My answer still works for the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

If your number is going to be 5 digits always, then the following might help. You can change to {5,6} if it is going to be 5 and 6 digits.

```
library(tidyverse)
my_text %>% 
  mutate(text1 = str_extract(text1, "\\b\\d{5}\\b"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have XML, but you've represented it in a corrupted form and you're trying to use regular expressions rather than 'xpath' queries. Re-instate the original XML, e.g., with quotes around version / encoding / standalone in the first line and version in the second line, as

```
txt = '
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
     <businessObjectChanges version="1">
       <table><datetime>1556122543608</datetime><name>header</name>
       <row>
         <datetime>1556122543608</datetime><transactionType>UPDATE</transactionType>
         <column><name>status</name><newValue>14</newValue><oldValue>13</oldValue><mimeType>INT</mimeType></column>
         <column><name>no_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>16593</newValue><oldValue>16593</oldValue></column>
       </row></table>
     </businessObjectChanges>'
```

and use the xpath language to extract the field you want

```
library(xml2)
xml = read_xml(txt)
xpath = "number(//name[text()='no_i']/following-sibling::newValue)"
xml_find_first(xml, xpath)
```

The xpath is a little advanced. `number()` coerces the value identified by the enclosed expression into a number. `//name[text()='no_i']` identifies the path through the document to the node `name` having text equal to `'no_i'`. `following-sibling::newValue` finds the sibling node (at the same level of nesting as the `name` node just identified) named `newValue`; the path is a little clearer with

```
> xml_path(xml_find_first(xml, "//name[text()='no_i']/following-sibling::newValue/text()"))
[1] "/businessObjectChanges/table/row/column[2]/newValue/text()"
```

A different, simpler, equally effective, xpath might be

```
number(//primaryKey/../newValue)
```

The idea would be to write a function that performs this on a single xml document

```
find_new_value <- function(txt, xpath) {
    xml = read_xml(txt)
    xml_find_first(xml, xpath)
}
```

and apply this to each element of your (corrected) XML text

```
xpath = "number(//primaryKey/../newValue)"
sapply(my_text$text1, find_new_value, xpath)
```

or in dplyr-land

```
my_text %>% mutate(value = find_new_value(text1, xpath))
```